# How to count records in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

**EDIT**

i want to ask how to get total count with data in web api. i have tried use `if` clause to count total record, but it only shows the total count and the data didn't show in xml format.

example from json format:

```
{
  "Count": 2, 
  "Data": [
    {
     "userid": 1,
     "name": "emily",
     "mobile": "98724954",
     "Age": 24,
     "Date": 2020-10-04T21:05:00
     },
     "userid": 2,
     "name": "peter",
     "mobile": "42896592",
     "Age": 35,
     "Date": 2021-05-25T11:20:00
     }
    ]
```

How to make the count like the example in XML format?

my code:

```
if(test.Count>0)
{
   return Ok(test.Count());
}
else
{
   return Ok("None");
};
```

results:

```
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">10</int>
```

class:

```
public class TestClass
    {

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        public int Access { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Count of what? What is `test`? Why does the if statement matter? Isn't 0 a valid count? Try not to return ints and strings from the same api

Comment: If Count is a public property that isn't being serialized to output automatically, then test is most likely a List. An array would have a length, and if it was another type then the Count would likely be serialized.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Again, what is `test`? Also, keep in mind that XML is considered insecure in many Web APIs and JSON responses are recommended

Answer (score 0):

Make a new class that contains a reference to your data AND has an int property for the count. Return an instance of the new class inside of the Ok call you return.

Comment: It seems `test` is already the class you're referring to

Comment: I don't believe it is. I think test is a List, unless the question poster says otherwise.

Comment: as @oneCricketeer said test is a class already

Comment: Then all you need to do is return test in your Ok, not test.Count. Ok creates a result and whatever object is passed to it will be serialized in the ouput.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an object that has both the count and the data. For example:

```
var result = new 
{ 
   Count = test.Count(),
   Data = test
}
return Ok(result);
```